# Exclude directory in a windows command line recursive search

Tags: windows, batch-file, search, directory

After researching how to move files w certain words in their title recursively...and assuming this is the result ( I have the code in a win11 .bat file which sits in the root of d:\ )

```
for /r %%a IN (*apples* *oranges*) do (
move /y "%%a" "d:\fruit" )
```

Is there a way I can EXCLUDE a specific directory from the search? The directory "d:\bananas" for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for /r %%a IN (*apples* *oranges*) do (
echo "%%a"|find /i "d:\bananas\" >nul
if errorlevel 1 move /y "%%a" "d:\fruit" )
```

The `find` sets `errorlevel` to `1` if the string is not found.

Answer (score 0):

This run faster because it does not execute the 17 Kb find.exe command *on each file*:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "exclude=d:\bananas"
for /r %%a IN (*apples* *oranges*) do (
   if "!exclude:%%~DPa=!" equ "%exclude%" move /y "%%a" "d:\fruit"
)
```

The `"!exclude:d:\bananas\=!"` part try to delete the path of each file from the variable. If the result is the same, the path is *not* in the variable...

You can also do a partial search of the beginning of the path of each file this way:

```
for /r %%a IN (*apples* *oranges*) do (
   set "filepath=%%~DPa"
   if "!filepath:d:\bananas=!" equ "!filepath!" move /y "%%a" "d:\fruit"
)
```

Comment: Well, I like the basic idea, but I'm afraid the first approach only excludes matching files located in the root of `D:`, and the second one also excludes a path like `D:\bananas_and_more`…

Comment: Then just use `"!filepath:d:\bananas\=!"` with a backslash in the right side (or any partial path you want).  PS - test _the time_ that this method takes vs. the `find` one.

Comment: The speed is the reason why I like the idea. When you append a `\ `in the first approach, only immediate children of the directory are excluded but not items in sub-directories – as intended, I guess…

Comment: @aschipfl - correct. My intention is to make ALL sub-directories of ```D:\``` as part of the search ( as in "search the entire drive EXCEPT for the ```d:\bananas``` directory." )

But the discussion between yourself and @Aacini brings up another scenario: How can I alter this to ignore multiple directories? For example, If I also wanted to exclude ``d:\path\grapes``?

In php you can use || as "or" so ```$a || $b``` would mean if either ```$a``` or ```$b``` is true, execute the code. But Im not sure how to do that in windows command line. 

DEFINATELY appreciate the hand holding!

Comment: @ErikMalson, for the **1**st approach – you can define multiple exclusions: `set "exclude1=d:\bananas\" & set "exclude2=d:\grapes\"`, then in the loop, `if "!exclude1:%%~DPa=!"=="%exclude1%" if "!exclude2:%%~DPa=!"=="%exclude2%" move …`; for the **2**nd approach: you can chain multiple `if` conditions: `if "!filepath:d:\bananas\=!"=="!filepath!" if "!filepath:d:\grapes\=!"=="!filepath!" move …`…